# Flutter Windows-Android Emulator Error ':cloud_firestore' error and ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, windows, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies

I am unable to continue using and learning flutter the way I'd want to because of the Android emulator gradle  **':cloud_firestore'** error I am encountering. I am using a Windows OS machine.

Initially, the error was this:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

After I added some dependencies by following a related short YouTube tutorial solution, it changed to:  `':cloud_firestore'`

So at the Moment anytime I try to run my Flutter with android emulator I get this error in the debug console:

```
problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
```

[image]

I tried Adding dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file, I expected after that the emulator to run fine but it didn't.

Here are modifications to my pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.25.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.1
  firebase_database: ^10.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.0
```

Comment: Please don't use images, check guidelines